# I upgraded my 14.04 from kernel 3.13.0-36-generic to 3.13.0-37-generic and the system hangs

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, upgrade, kernel

Everything works fine with kernel 3.13.0-36.  After updating to the new kernel and rebooting, the video looks like it might not be right and the system hangs after logging in.

Used grub to boot back into the old kernel and that works fine.  System is a Dell Latitude with NVidia video.

Answer (score 0):

Simply boot to a previous kernel  and reinstall the kernel version and type the following

sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot now

Comment: I get the following message (trimmed to fit)

sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image
Reading package lists... Done
Package linux-image is a virtual package provided by:
  linux-image-3.13.0-39-lowlatency 3.13.0-39.66
  linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic 3.13.0-39.66
  linux-image-3.13.0-37-lowlatency 3.13.0-37.64
  linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic 3.13.0-37.64
  linux-image-3.13.0-36-lowlatency 3.13.0-36.63
  linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic 3.13.0-36.63
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'linux-image' has no installation candidate

Comment: Should I use this

sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0.37-generic linux-image 

Also what about the linux-extra-3.13.0.37-generic?

Comment: First reinstall without the extra.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0.36-generic linux-image.   Sudo update-grub   sudo reboot now.  If every is working fine go to the dash - type update - and execute. Reboot.